# How would I use a regular expression to find calls to functions?

Tags: regex

Suppose I want find all function calls in my listing (a vb.net listing), and I have the function name.
first I thought I could do a regular expression such as:

```
myfunc\(  .*  \)
```

That should work even if the function spans multiple lines, assuming that the dot is interpreted as including newlines (there is an option to  do this in dot-net)

but then I realized that some of my arguments themselves could be function calls.
in other words:
myfunc( a,b,c,d(),e ), 
which means that the parentheses don't match up.

so I thought that since the main function call usually is the first item on a line, I could do this:

```
^myfunc( .* \) $
```

The idea is that the function is the first item on a line (^) and the last paren is the last item on a line ($).  but that doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you're looking for calls to a specific function and you know how many arguments it takes, you can try something like `myfunc(.*, .*, .*)`. In general though, no regex will be perfect since most programming language syntax is based on a context-free grammar (see the Chomsky hierarchy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)

Answer (score 3):

You can't. By design, regular expressions cannot deal with recursion which is needed here.

For more information, you might want to read the first answer here: [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

And yes, I know that some special "regular expressions" do allow for recursion. However, in most cases, this means that you are doing something horrible. It is much better to use something that can actually understand the syntax of your language.

Comment: I don't think recursion is needed here, because VB.net ends every line with an underscore, unless it is the end of the statement.  So I should be able to search for all text up to a parenthesis that is followed by an "end line".  I would think something like: ^myfunc\(.....\)$ --however, using regular expression in dot-net is tricky, because if you want to match multiple lines, you use an option that changes the meaning of "dollar sign" and "caret" to not be start and and end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but if you want to find all uses of your function you can use Visual Studio.  Just right click on the function, and then select `Find All References`:

[image]

Visual Studio will show you the results. You can then double click on each line and Visual Studio will take you there.

[image]

Comment: I did know that Visual Studio can find references, but what I want to do is write a program that goes through a folder, and collects all the calls to a particular function, even if they span multiple lines, puts them in a file, and alphabetizes them, removes duplicates, and sees if any of the calls have mistakes in them, such as switching the position of two variables.  In other words, it would be a debugging aid.